# Additional sort order option to sort answers by 'My Votes'

Tags: feature-request

There are many times where I will search for an answer to a question that I have looked up in the past (e.g. something I don't do often that I then proceed to forget by the time I need to do it again).

Often these will be solutions that have been around for years and thus have a tendency to pick a large collection of varying answers.

Generally, the ability to sort answers based on 'Votes' is great, this is what I use myself and it usually ensures the best answers are at the top. However, this is only really beneficial if it's a new problem I am trying to solve. In the scenario I have explained above, I almost *always* want to see the answer that *I* upvoted, and I don't care about any other answers that have higher votes.

So my suggestion is, that we have a new sort order. Something like 'My Votes'.

This order will push *my votes* to the top, the fallback would ideally be the logic currently used for the 'Votes' sort order.

To simplify what I am trying to suggest:

```
ORDER BY HasMyVote THEN BY NumberOfVotes
```

Of course, it would be wise to take into account that my downvotes should be pushed to the bottom. Lets say for example there is a field for MyVoteOrder where UpVote = 0, NoVote = 1, DownVote = 2. The query would be:

```
ORDER BY MyVoteOrder ASC THEN BY NumberOfVotes DESC
```

(By the way, I am not suggesting these are valid queries. They are simply to help explain what I am looking for)